# Dependency Injection of Interface

Tags: php, laravel, oop, dependency-injection, interface

Hi I'm getting an error of should be an instance of interface

```
App\Repositories\Traits\PhotoService::__construct() must be an instance of AwsServiceInterface, instance
```

Here's what I have so far

```
namespace App\Repositories\Interfaces;

interface AwsServiceInterface
{
 //...
}
```

Now I have this class

```
namespace App\Repositories\Interfaces;

use App\Repositories\Interfaces\AwsServiceInterface;

class CloudFrontService implements AwsServiceInterface
{

    public function __construct()
   {
   }
}
```

Now I'm using a dependency injection on this class

```
namespace App\Repositories\Traits;

use App\Repositories\Interfaces\AwsServiceInterface;

class PhotoService
{
    protected $service;

    public function __construct(AwsServiceInterface $service)
    {
        $this->service = $service;
    }

    public function getAuthParams($resource, $search_key = '')
    {
        // Execute a function from a class that implements AwsServiceInterface
    }
```

And I'm calling the PhotoService class like this

```
$photo_service = new PhotoService(new CloudFrontService());
echo $photo_service->getAuthParams($resource);
```

But somehow I'm getting this error

```
FatalThrowableError: Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Repositories\Traits\PhotoService::__construct() must be an instance of AwsServiceInterface, instance of App\Repositories\Interfaces\CloudFrontService given
```

Comment: I've just copied your code and tried to execute it. It works well for me. From your question, it is not clear what namespace are imported in the file where you create new PhotoService instance. Maybe there is some mistake.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved my problem. For those of you having the same issue make sure you do this step.
1. as mentioned by @Amit double check on the service provider that the service is bind under register function
2. Make sure to do

- php artisan clear-compile
- php artisan cache:clear
- php artisan config:clear

Answer (score 1):

In your `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` class add following code in `register()` method:

```
$this->app->bind(
    'App\Repositories\Interfaces\AwsServiceInterface',
    'App\Repositories\Interfaces\CloudFrontService'
);
```

and then you can use it as:

```
$photo_service = app(PhotoService::class);
echo $photo_service->getAuthParams($resource);
```

Comment: I just did what you have mentioned but it didn't work. But I solved it now I just needed to do php artisan clear-compile

Answer (score 0):

You are having a problem with namespacing.  The typehint that you are using isn't complete for what you are looking for.

Just guessing but I think that you want to change the typehint to be:

```
 public function __construct(App\Repositories\Interfaces\AwsServiceInterface $service)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php

Comment: It's not the typehint.. I tried your suggestion but still the same

Comment: Then the problem is with the namespace where you are doing: `new CloudFrontService()`

Comment: Updated my question I also included the namespaces and use. Can you point out what I'm doing wrong? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind implementation to that interface. [Here's](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/container#binding-interfaces-to-implementations) an example.

Laravel itself does not know what implementation you want to use for this interface, you need to specify that yourself.